# Thonny IDE different directory then terminal when running python file

Tags: python, picamera

I have a discord bot python file I am running and editing in Thonny IDE I get an error where it cannot find the specified directory, when I run the code for pi camera: `camera.capture('./files/meeka.jpg', resize=(2592, 1944))`.

The file is located in the directory: `/home/pi/Desktop/MeekaCam/.py` and works fine when it is opened and ran in Thonny IDE.

However when i launch it in terminal using `python3 /home/pi/Desktop/MeekaCam/discord_bot_meeka.py` the directory it uses seems to be `/home/pi`.

Why would this be happening or how could I make it use the same directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.` is shorthand for the current directory, so will vary depending on where it is being run.

It is handy if this is your intention, but not really best practice.

You should use a fully qualified path e.g `/home/pi/Desktop/MeekaCam/files/meeka.jpg`

You can use `~` in place of `/home/pi`